# Why if words.istitle() == True: doesn't work? py 3.0

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a programme which changes title to "NAME", but it doesn't work when I try to check if the word is title or not. It always outputs F

```
s = str(input()).split(" ")
for words in s:
    print(s)
    if words.istitle() == False:
        print("F", s)
    if words.istitle() == True:
        print("T")
```

I work in python 3.0

Comment: What is your input? Your code generally works.

Comment: Just to add: comparing boolean values to boolean literals doesn't really make sense. The resulting value is a boolean, *but you already had a boolean*. You can should just use `if words.istitle(): ... else: ...`

Comment: I can confirm that the code does work. Maybe you misunderstood what `istitle()` does - it checks whether the first, and ONLY the first letter of the string is upper-case.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to create a programme which changes title to "NAME"

Nowhere in your code do you do this. `str.title` makes the first letter capital and rest lower for each word in the string. What you're looking for is `str.upper`

```
>>> 'nAmE FoObAr'.upper()
NAME FOOBAR
>>> 'nAmE FoObAr'.title()
Name Foobar
>>> 'Name'.istitle()
True
>>> 'NAME'.isupper()
True
>>> 'NAME'.istitle()
False
>>> 'Name'.isupper()
False
```

Comment: Thank you!! I've made it :)